# Is there a limit to how many people should be on the bimah when the Torah is removed / returned to the ark?

Tags: synagogue, torah-service

As I understand, only one person needs to be on the bimah to take out one Torah (as on most Shabbatot) from and return the Torah to the ark - the *chazzan*.

Is there a specific *halacha* that says that someone else should take it out and hand it to the chazzan?

In many shuls, I see a larger contingent as follows (to take out 1 Torah):

- Chazzan
- Someone giving the Torah to him
- Someone to open the ark
- Rabbi
- Shul president

Except for the rabbi, who is already sitting on the bimah, the others are not there, previously, and they go up to the bimah for the Torah service.

Is there any halacha stating how many people is excessive? (I'm not questioning *why* so many shuls have been doing this for some time. They have their reasons. I'm questioning if there is any halacha or a rabbinical opinion against doing this.)

Comment: Separate people to open the aron and take out the Torah?

Comment: Why is the Chazzan there? The Chazzan stands at the Amud. The whole point of having someone else go get the Torah is so he doesn't need to move.

Comment: @DoubleAA, most schuls I've been to have the sha"tz go from the 'amud to the duchan to take the sefer.

Comment: @noach then what's the point of the other guy going up if the chazzan is going up anyway?

Comment: @DoubleAA, to open the aron and remove the sefer/seforim therefrom

Comment: @noac that doesn't really address my question

Comment: @DoubleAA  "then what's the point of the other guy going up if the chazzan is going up anyway?" That's the main part of my question. I'm asking if there is any halacha or preference for someone to specifically hand the Torah to the chazzan, or can he take it out himself.

Comment: @danf that is definitely not the main part of your question. Your question is about an upper limit on people on the bimah

Comment: The thought of a crowd around the aron is very humorous to me.

Comment: @ezra You have NO idea :-( It would be more humorous if you didn't realize how many of these people "fight" to have the honor of being up there.

Comment: I've also seen the gabbai go up to point out which sefer to use